# Fixed Rest Endpoints

Tags: java, tomcat7, war, versioning, endpoint

I have a war file deployed on tomcat ( /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps folder ), say, rest-api-webapp-0.0.1.war 
To access the rest endpoint *check*, exposed in this war, I use curl in the format
    `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "remarks=Tester" https://localhost:8080/rest-api-webapp-0.0.1/check` 
 
 The problem I face is, whenever I up the patch/major/minor versions of my webapp, I need to change the curl appropriately (say the version is now 0.1.4, then the curl must change as `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "remarks=Tester" https://localhost:8080/rest-api-webapp-0.1.4/check`. I donot wish to change the way the client calls the endpoint (because it requires the client to upgrade their app, which they resent and see as high maintenance) Can this be avoided by doing something like this 
Create a symbolic link as below 
 `ln -s rest-api-webapp-0.0.1.war rest-api` 
 inside the /var/log/tomcat7/webapps folder so that whennever I up the version, I just change the symlink to point to the new version and the client need not do anything to use the new version of the api.
 In effect, I need the api endpoint to be fixed and not change as and when I up the versions on the server. 
**For Ex**: I need the endpoint to be fixed as `https:gva.atr.in/colouring-api/check` and whenever I have a major change in the controllers and all that I need to do is just update the symlink and not change the endpoint. 
 If you find that this approach is flawed, please show me the right direction as I have been trying to read about this from the past 2 days, but found very less articles that address my problem.

Comment: read the tomcat documentation about servlet (URI) mapping and configurations

Comment: Thanks @mschenk74. I did read the documents and understood what I need to do to arrive at the solution I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read the tomcat documentation and realised that I need to create a symbolic link to the war file and give the symbolic file the war extension. So If this is what you have in your *tomcat webapps* directory 
`/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps user1$ ls 
drwxr-xr-x  11 user1  wheel       374 Oct 19 21:52 .
drwxr-xr-x   9 user1  admin       306 Oct 19 19:36 ..
drwxr-xr-x  19 user1  wheel       646 Aug 29 20:19 ROOT
drwxr-xr-x  55 user1  wheel      1870 Aug 29 20:19 docs
drwxr-xr-x   4 user1  wheel       136 Oct 19 19:46 rest-api-webapp-0.2.1
-rw-r--r--   1 user1  wheel  48258097 Oct 19 19:46 rest-api-webapp-0.2.1.war
drwxr-xr-x   7 user1  wheel       238 Aug 29 20:19 host-manager
drwxr-xr-x   8 user1  wheel       272 Aug 29 20:19 manager`

 Do this,

 `ln -s rest-api-webapp-0.2.1.war rest-api.war` 
 So that the directory looks like this (Wait for sometime for the tomcat engine to deploy the new war) 
`drwxr-xr-x  11 user1  wheel       374 Oct 19 21:52 .
drwxr-xr-x   9 user1  admin       306 Oct 19 19:36 ..
drwxr-xr-x  19 user1  wheel       646 Aug 29 20:19 ROOT
drwxr-xr-x   4 user1  wheel       136 Oct 19 21:52 rest-api
drwxr-xr-x   4 user1  wheel       136 Oct 19 19:46 rest-api-webapp-0.2.1
-rw-r--r--   1 user1  wheel  48258097 Oct 19 19:46 rest-api-webapp-0.2.1.war
lrwxr-xr-x   1 user1  wheel        25 Oct 19 21:51 rest-api.war -> rest-api-webapp-0.2.1.war
drwxr-xr-x   7 user1  wheel       238 Aug 29 20:19 host-manager
drwxr-xr-x   8 user1  wheel       272 Aug 29 20:19 manager` 
 
If needed restart your tomcat and you can use the curl command like this
 
 `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "remarks=Tester" https://localhost:8080/rest-api/check`
 
 totally not bothering about the major, minor, patch versions. 
 All that you need to do once you have a new version is 
 `unlink rest-api`
`ln -s rest-api-webapp-X.Y.Z.war rest-api.war`